# How to get class values in static method

Tags: python, django

I want to get the field value like we use self in Django models.

```
class UserModel(Model):
    id = IDField()
    uid = TextField()

    @classmethod
     def get_user(cls):
         return cls.uid
```

The class method, keep returning NONE instead of the string value of the uid field. Did I miss something?

This is from the Firestore Python wrapper https://octabyte.io/FireO/quick-start/

Comment: The class does not hold any data.  It is the class instances that hold the data.

Comment: Thanks. I am noticing that!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@classmethod` and `cls` you can only get empty values. It is because you have basic class schema from which you can create objects (aka instances of that class).

To get value of current objects it has to be from `self`, so standard method. Then you can get a value of this particular object instance.

I didn't even find mention of a `@classmethod` in the Firestore Python. Most likely you don't need that decorator for now.